# Chromium Browser kiosk not saving cookies

Tags: chromium, docker

I'm running chromium browser in kiosk mode in a docker container. The page loads a login screen. You sign in and the page gives you a cookie so that you never have to login again. This does work on my mac's chromium browser and windows as well but on my raspberry pi it doesn't seem to save cookies on exit.

I'm using the project [here](https://github.com/jayatvars/balena-chromium-kiosk) on github.

Maybe I need to try changing my flags on start up? right now they are:

`chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-infobars $URL_LAUNCHER_URL --disable-gpu`

The site that it opens into to is not a local one but instead a remote site at an ip address. so the issue is not the common `file://` prefix I've seen so much of when researching this. I am going to an actual site.

My logs look like this:

```
 X.Org X Server 1.20.4
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser  X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser  Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-48-generic armv8l Raspbian
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser  Current Operating System: Linux bk-rpi-629ec76 4.19.71 #1 SMP Mon Jan 6 19:29:19 UTC 2020 armv7l
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser  Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1080 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1920 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=null rootfstype=ext4 rootwait vt.global_cursor_default=0 root=PARTUUID=0653c4e0-02 rootwait
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser  Build Date: 05 June 2019  12:49:54PM
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser  xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1+rpt1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser  Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser      Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser      to make sure that you have the latest version.
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser  Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser      (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser      (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser  (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Jan 29 20:53:06 2020
29.01.20 12:53:06 (-0800)  browser  (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
29.01.20 12:53:21 (-0800)  browser  [139:366:0129/205321.397269:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
29.01.20 12:53:21 (-0800)  browser  [139:366:0129/205321.741725:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
29.01.20 12:53:21 (-0800)  browser  [139:366:0129/205321.742165:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
29.01.20 12:53:22 (-0800)  browser  [139:380:0129/205322.697631:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(632)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
29.01.20 12:53:22 (-0800)  browser  [139:380:0129/205322.700946:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(632)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.GetDisplayDevice: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
29.01.20 12:53:22 (-0800)  browser  [139:380:0129/205322.704045:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(632)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.EnumerateDevices: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
```